# Use of adjectives: As a book title would it be "Anna gentile - professore gentile" or "Gentile Anna - Gentile professore"?

Tags: adjectives

In Italian normally adjectives come after the noun; hence "Anna gentile" and "professore gentile". But if the use is a special one, as with a book title, would it normally be reversed, so to say, giving "Gentile Anna - Gentile Professore"?

Comment: I wouldn't even say “normally”: for Italian adjective to come after nouns, it is a vague tendency, more often than not to be violated. Think *buon giorno*, *una bella giornata*, *un forte mal di testa*, *sette colli*, *una vecchia storia*, not to mention cases where the position of the adjective changes the meaning of the phrase, such as *diverse persone* (several people) vs. *persone diverse* (different people).

Comment: In any case, do you mean “Gentile Anna” etc. as in the beginning of a letter? “Dear Anna” etc.?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are right, I seem to have exaggerated the case with adjectives. In the case of "Gentile Anna - Gentile Professore", it is a question of how to translate a forthcoming essay/book title. The author claims he heard the expression "Gentile Anna, gentile professore", from the mouth of a staff member to describe a much-loved old professor in an Italian university. But did he mishear, I thought? Would it more likely have been "Anna gentile, professore gentile"?

Comment: I don't get the meaning of the sentence he heard. A female _professore_ is a _professoressa_, if _Anna_ is meant to be the professor's name. However, either position of the adjective makes (little :-) ) sense.

Comment: related question: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order?rq=1

Comment: Hey, what if Anna Gentile were the full name of the professor? http://www.gentileanna.unisalento.it/ She doesn't seem to be "an old professor", though.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. The author I'm dealing with seems to be trying to think of the Italian equivalent of a worker praising (in just a few words) her boss of many years with the phrase "Kind Anna, kind professor" (or "Beloved Anna... our beloved professor"). So "Gentile Anna, gentile professoressa" sounds unnatural?

Comment: Oh, now it is clearer. It would more idiomatic ti say something like «Anna, la nostra cara professoressa».

Comment: "Gentile Anna, Gentile Professore" può essere l'incipit di una lettera formale rivolta da una persoan con una certa confidenza ma allo stesso tempo rispettosa.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context:

- If you want specify that they are gentle or kind, say: "Anna è gentile, il professore è gentile".
- If you are speaking with an important person say "gentile Anna, gentile professore" to open a *formal* speech.

N.B: "gentile Anna" and "gentile professore" don't mean that Anna and the teacher are gentle or kind, but only that you are speaking in a formal language to them.

Comment: Mind the fact that, as made clear in the comments by the OP, the “professore” is supposed to be Anna herself.