# The difference between "la settimana scorsa" vs "la scorsa settimana"?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Is there any difference between the two phrase `la settimana scorsa` vs `la scorsa settimana`?

For instance, I found the following sentence in my Rosetta Stone program:

> Mio padre è morto la scorsa settimana.

But while I don't remember the sentence, I also read the sentence that uses `la settimana scorsa`.

Similarly, does the `la settimana prossima` have the same meaning as `la prossima settimana`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No there is no difference in meaning between:

> - *la settimana scorsa/prossima*

vs

> - *la scorsa/prossima settimana*.

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la%20settimana%20scorsa%2Cla%20scorsa%20settimana%2C%20la%20settimana%20prossima%2C%20la%20prossima%20settimana&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cla%20settimana%20scorsa%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20scorsa%20settimana%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20settimana%20prossima%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cla%20prossima%20settimana%3B%2Cc0) shows that usages of both forms are common.

- You can refer [here](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order) for rules regarding adjectives order in the Italian language:

Comment: Thanks. It's interesting to see that `la settimana scorsa` is used more often than `la scorsa settimana` but in the case of `prossima`, it's reversed.

Answer (score 0):

The two options are identical in the meaning, in some regions "la scorsa settimana" is used more often than "la settimana scorsa" in others is the opposite ( depends on the dialect influence),anyway depends also to the position in the sentence: "la settimana scorsa sono stato in montagna" is more common than "la scorsa settimana sono stato in montagna". But you have to know that the difference is pratically zero.