# Which is the proper word order: “anima bellissima” or “bellissima anima”?

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I would like to understand which is the correct word order in the sentence: *anima bellissima* or *bellissima anima*.

Comment: In Italian there is not a preferred order: both choices are acceptable, although they convey subtly different meanings depending on the context. In order for us to help you we need more details about what you want to say. And by the way it is *bellissima* not *bellisima*.

Comment: @DenisNardin I think your comment should be evolved into a proper answer.

Comment: @LuciaBentivoglio I would like to give more time for the OP to improve his/her question, so that we can give a more nuanced answer. In absence of further edits, I'll write something tomorrow evening.

Comment: @DenisNardin: Anche io sono dell'avviso che dovresti convertire in risposta il tuo commento, poi se CaseyB amplia la domanda, puoi sempre ampliare la risposta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order/1256#1256

Answer (score 3):

In Italian there is not a preferred order: both choices are acceptable, although they convey subtly different meanings depending on the context. A famous example is the [commercial of the "Cinghiale" brushes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2kjjQiRo5oA), where the *pennello grande* is a big brush, while a *grande pennello* is a great brush (as in, a very good one).

I would say that the most neuter choice is *anima bellissima*, but we would really need the context of the sentence to be more sure.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a correct order: it depends upon the framework.
Using 'Bellissima anima' makes you feel more archaic and poetic to your intercolutor, though. Using the name + adjective order is a bit childish.