# È una sana paura - adjective position

Tags: adjectives, word-order

I'm aware that most adjectives come after the noun they qualify, but certain adjectives usually come before the noun: bello, bravo, brutto, buono, caro, cattivo, giovane, grande, intero, lungo, nuovo, picolo, stesso, vecchio, vero. Some of these adjectives have different meanings when they are before or after the noun (eg "un grande uomo" = a great man, "un uomo grande" = a large/tall man).

I have recently read the following sentence in an Italian learning tool:

> È una sana paura.

Why is "sana" before the noun in this sentence? Is it because the adjective has a figurative meaning? Would "è una paura sana" be wrong?

Comment: You can also find more information in [_Sulla posizione dell'aggettivo qualificativo in italiano_](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/posizione-dellaggettivo-qualificativo-italia) by Accademia della Crusca

Comment: Moreover your question can already be answered by [_What is the rule for adjective order?_](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order?rq=1)

Comment: This question has received some closing as duplicate votes by several users of this community, but I reopened it by mistake. Sorry :(!!