# Ordine degli aggettivi

Tags: grammar, adjectives

Sembra che in inglese ci sia un ordine particolare per raggruppare aggettivi:

> “Adjectives in English absolutely have to be in this order: opinion-size-age-shape-colour-origin-material-purpose Noun. So you can have a lovely little old rectangular green French silver whittling knife. But if you mess with that word order in the slightest you’ll sound like a maniac. It’s an odd thing that every English speaker uses that list, but almost none of us could write it out.”

Source: [BBC.COM](https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20160908-the-language-rules-we-know-but-dont-know-we-know)

Esiste una regola simile in italiano ?

Comment: Benvenuto su ItalianSE!

Comment: Puoi dare la fonte del capoverso che citi?

Comment: @DaG sembra essere questa: https://www.bbc.com/culture/article/20160908-the-language-rules-we-know-but-dont-know-we-know

Comment: @Hachi: Grazie mille. In realtà l'avevo trovata anch'io, ma il mio intento era soprattutto ricordare all'OP che è importante menzionare le proprie fonti.

Comment: Potenzialmente un [duplicato](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1248/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order/1256#1256)?

Comment: Strano, a me insegnarono l'acronimo OPSHACOM (OPinion, SHape, Age, Colour, Origin, Material), dove "shape" racchiudeva sia la forma che la dimensione.